# How to get the bitmap of complete scrolled area of view implemented with GestureListener with Scroller

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-gesture, android-scroll

**What I have Tried:**

I'm drawing shapeDrawables in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` in a custom view with using [GestureListener](https://gist.github.com/LOG-TAG/c16cd58bbb8333b8bf0d) in view for **Scroller** (not scrollview). code is available on **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/LOG-TAG/c16cd58bbb8333b8bf0d)**

I'm trying to take the **Bitmap** image of that view which contains **`GestureListener`** with  **`Scroller`** implementation

```
public void save(String fname, View view) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();

            File f = new File(filename, "myImage.png");
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("file created " + f.toString());
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);


            view.getDrawingCache();


            view.measure(view.getScrollX(), view.getScrollY());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

The code working fine! but what UI required is I want to take the image (screenshot) whole view which is drawing with scroller! shape drawn on out of the screen(visible on gesture Scroller) is not displayed in the image what I saved in above code. I'm failed to implement view calculations of the shape views drawn out side the initial width and and height area!

tried with this but failed:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    view.getWidth() + view.getScrollX(), view.getHeight()
                            + view.getScrollY(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

**getScrollX()** returns 0 all the time !

Comment: your Scroller usage is wrong: you call fling() but never calling computeScrollOffset() and getCurrX()/getCurrY() which is the whole idea of Scroller

Comment: addressed it, sorry for post the wrong code, but still not able to get the bitmap of full view including scrolled area!

Comment: there is no such thing like "full view": Log.d getWidth()/getHeight() and see the logcat

Comment: probably I have to scale down (zoom out) before capturing the bitmap !

Comment: did you Log.d the width/height of your view?

Comment: yes width: 1024 height: 600    1024/600

Comment: so what do you want to scale down? the view has always the fixed size and in your case i think its the full display size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63575/discussion-between-log-tag-and-pskink).